# Am I the only one confused by the names Iteratee, Enumerator, and Enumeratee?

Tags: haskell, naming, loops

I love iteratees as a paradigm for IO, but I have some concerns about the names.

I am having trouble developing a relationship with these names. Could someone explain their origin? The definition `data Stream a = Chunks [a] | EOF` is worse, if anything. That doesn't gibe with my previous notion of a stream, because it is only a small part of the overall stream.

It seems like if `Iteratee`s consume things, `Enumerator`s produce them, and `Enumeratee`s do both that names like `Sink`, `Source`, and `Transformer` or `Consumer`, `Producer`, and `Transformer` might be better choices? Is there some reason apart from convention why these names wouldn't fit the concepts well?

Of all the eleventy-seven variations on this theme out there, I'm intrigued by [John Millikin's take on this old Haskell-Cafe thread about a variation which statically eliminates the "divergent iteratee" problem](http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/14463096.html) (the problem of an iteratee that returns Continue in response to EOF), but my problems with the names apply to pretty much all of the versions I have yet seen.

Comment: While I agree that the naming can be confusing, this sounds more like a rant than a question, and SO is not the place for that.

Comment: @hammar I didn't intend to be ranting. I legitimately do want to know if anyone is aware of a reason why the alternate name suggestions I made are inappropriate, or alternatively of other "easier" names that might be appropriate. My apologies. I have made edits to remove snarkiness, please feel free to go further if I missed something. I really would like to see a debate over the answer to this question.

Comment: SO isn't really a place for debates, either. I think [haskell-cafe](http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/haskell-cafe) or [r/haskell](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/) would be more appropriate places to have this discussion.

Comment: @hammar Fair point, again, apologies.